# How to filter lines written to log by gnu-screen

Tags: bash, logging, filter, gnu-screen

I have a device that I can log it's output using screen:

```
screen -L log.txt /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

and the log.txt file will have entries like this:

```
Seconds:      2001.609
Centigrade:   38.780
Humidity %:   29.534

Seconds:      2002.756
Centigrade:   38.950
Humidity %:   29.274
```

with a blank line between each block of data. I'd like to drop the blank lines and the Seconds line to get:

```
Centigrade:   38.780
Humidity %:   29.534
Centigrade:   38.950
Humidity %:   29.274
```

Is there anyway to do this with screen? Or is post processing the only option? If a grep can be run then I can also add an awk to produce:

```
2001.609, 38.780, 29.534
2002.756, 38.950, 29.274
```

Is screen the best tool for this logging? It seems not.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: If you are not going to interact with the device, then you can simply read straight from it with `awk </dev/ttyUSB0 '....'` and extract the wanted fields. You can set the speed first with `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` and perhaps also choose `raw -echo` and similar options at the same time.

Comment: @meuh thank you for the suggestion to use stty, You can submit that as an answer with the following code `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200; egrep -i "humidity|centigrade" < /dev/ttyUSB0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not going to interact with the device, then you can simply read straight from it with `awk </dev/ttyUSB0 '....'` and extract the wanted fields. You can set the speed first with `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` and perhaps also choose other stty options like `raw -echo` at the same time.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
awk </dev/ttyUSB0  '
 /^Seconds:/    { s = $2; next }
 /^Centigrade:/ { c = $2; next }
 /^Humidity %:/ { h = $3; printf "%s, %s, %s\n",s,c,h }
'
```